# Ubuntu doesn't recognize headphone on startup or restart

Tags: 19.04

If I keep headphone plugged in to laptop Ubuntu doesn't recognize headphone on startup or restart.
Always have to plug out and plug in the headphone. Its a hectic process.

Comment: If it works if you re plug the headphones it may just be the sound device. Has the headphones worked on startup or reboot before?

Comment: They work only when I plug them in after a restart or startup, if I keep them plugged in ubuntu doesnt detect headphones on next boot, this is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Try running "alsamixer" in terminal. There's a manual mute button, possibly an auto-detect toggle.

- Either way if you can find the unmute: that might be more helpful.
- As for solving the autodetect... Frankly ive never solved that.

It works automatically for some, and not for others. I searched for a while and gave up.

Dunno if its a "good answer" 
but if it helps, there you go.

If someones got a better answer... ok.

Comment: thank you, so far you seem to know my actual problem, but if I accept your answer ubuntu developers will never come up with any solution.

Comment: While I share your ire... To be fair: Proprietary devices seldom have much open source support. They typically do the minimum + whatever they must to make money. Thats said, there are certainly many things down that road I feel get neglected via laze.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are running Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10. If you are restarting Ubuntu or restarting from Windows 10 to boot into Ubuntu, sound may not work. It is a confirmed bug affecting many users.
a temporary workaround is to shut down from Windows 10 and then boot into Ubuntu directly. This will bring back the sound.

Comment: no I am just running ubuntu 19.04, so this is not the actual issue